# New pair of ssh keys cannot connet to gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, key, gitlab, ssh-keys

accidentally I deleted the private an public key from the .ssh folder. Now i can't clone from the gitlab repository because of this problem:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`
```

I checked the permission, created a new account with new keys, create again new keys but nothing solved the problem

I have searched also a lot but the result was the same.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

*Heh...* If you *deleted* the private and/or the public key that the remote recognizes, and you did not have the foresight to keep a *backup,* then you're going to have to re-register your *new* keys. ("Effectively starting over," because the recognized-keys that you formerly used have now been lost in the digital gloom ...)